# Adding a banner image under header

Tags: css, banner

I'm trying to add a banner under the header of my site and cannot figure out how to do it. Please see the picture for reference.

[image: Example Picture]

When I try to add an image, it will act like a background image for a menu under the header - not what I'm trying to do. I'd like a fixed banner.

This is the css I added but it acts like a background for a menu under the header.

```
.nav-secondary .wrap {
    background: url( https://dreaminginyellow.com/diy-custom-design-yellow-strips/) bottom center no-repeat;
}
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: Well... you are defining it as a background; so it will behave as a background... You should share your HTML structure as well

Comment: Thank you. Where is my HTML structure? Sorry - very new at this!

Comment: The location really depends. If this is a static page it's probably in a file called `index.html` or something similar ending in `.html`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry guys, can't seem to find any .html files. I'm looking in the theme editor Stylesheet CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposing you want to do something like this?

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.banner {
  height: 100px;
  background: url(https://dreaminginyellow.com/diy-custom-design-yellow-strips/) bottom center no-repeat
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h2>Header Text</h2>
  </header>
  <div class="banner"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Content</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="banner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! So where do I put the <div class=container">...code? I tried adding it to the Additional CSS but it didn't work.

Comment: Okay, first I think we need to know more about how you are building this site.. are you using Wordpress or something like that? The example above just shows one approach if you can create the whole component... You should have access to the site/template's HTML somewhere. You can only put CSS on the CSS file... the HTML should have its own file most likely

Comment: I'm on Wordpress with the Refined theme from Restored 316. dreaminginyellow.com. I really appreciate all of your help

Comment: Okay then you need to find where to edit the piece of code where you want that banner, see if you can go the page where you want the banner and Edit it... Read this guide https://wpbuffs.com/how-to-edit-source-code-in-wordpress/

Comment: I added the CSS but the original image still shows under the header - the line with a diamond on each end.

Comment: Its not just adding the CSS; you have to create a structure in HTML that represents what you want, and then you style that with the CSS; most likely my code will not work, I'm just using some generic classes to show a quick example; the theme you are using might have some patterns as well